# How can I create a Docker image for Solaris+Java (With JAVA_HOME)?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, solaris-10

I've tried though, but seems docker isn't supported yet. Still if any ways of doing so is available, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No. Here is the [compatibility matrix](https://success.docker.com/article/compatibility-matrix). It is not ported to Solaris. I don't know if there is any plan to leverage on top of Solaris Zones, never heard of it.

From the scope of Docker on Linux,  Docker is basically glorified `chroot` with resource isolation provided by Linux Kernel's *namespaces* feature and resource accounting provided by the Kernel's *control groups* feature (I am skipping a lot more things like AUFS, SELinux etc.). Don't think about Docker a virtual machine manager/hypervisor. It may look like one, feel like one but it is not. Every process, running in a container (doesn't necessarily Docker - You can make them with shell scripts too) is under the control of the host's running kernel (Linux).

The processes inside a container environment won't see processes (or resources) outside the container. However the reverse is possible, from the host, the kernel can see everything in every container and kill them if they misbehave. On modern Linux systems, you are always in a container environment even if you haven't heard about Docker. Solaris, is a whole different beast altogether and I don't think you can do what you are thinking of, with Docker or LXC or anything that is built around *cgroups* and *namespaces*. Your best possible option is to use a hypervisor and virtualize hardware.